# frequency of DC current

Tags: dc, frequency

What is the frequency of dc current,  Please tell me, why frequency of DC current is zero in detail. 
Thank you.
I hope anyone really tell me .

Answer (score 2):

frequency is the amount of times a signal is repeated per second. for example a square signal goes like this: 1-0-1-0-1-0 in 1 second. Then the frequency is 3Hz. A DC signal is constant. As the signal is constant there is nothing to be 'repeated' so the frequency is 0.

Comment: And if the frequency is zero then it is forever unchanging, so you can only have a pure DC current if it has always existed! Anything else is a combination of DC and AC.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking for any practical DC source its **NOT** zero.

```
                              f = 1/T
```

where f is frequency (Hz) and T - the time of the period in seconds.

For f **to be zero** the T (the period) must be **infinitely long**.

All practical DC sources are switched ON - last a period of time and then are turned OFF. The period will be the time ON + the time OFF. This, of course, would be a very large number (of seconds) and the associated (fundamental) frequency would be very very small (approaching zero but not quite zero).

*(There is also the harmonic frequencies to be considered due to the rapid step change - but that's a different question. (Fourier analysis)).*

Putting a few numbers into the problem will illustrate the point.

take T = 100, 1000, 1000000 seconds

this would give f = 0.01 Hz , 0.001 Hz, 0.000001Hz and so on.

It doesn't matter how big T gets, f is never zero but for all practical purposes its value is near enough and engineers are practical folk.